# how to generate random time series for a given one, including all trends?

Tags: time-series

I have a 250-time points series of actual data and I want to generate a similar time series including all its curves

first, I was interested to know its probability distribution and see if it fits other distributions, after fitting, it was Normal and Lognormal seem better. So I generated 250 points of Lognormal but they came absolutely random resembling no properties of the original time series (Lognormal are illustrated in the second chart)

The original time series it looks like this

[image]

My generated Lognormal according to the data parameters looks like this

[image]

the data is as follows
1800
1650
1850
2050
2150
1950
1700
1850
2200
2270
1950
1730
1850
2200
2350
1950
1780
1930
2200
2400
2270
1920
2080
2340
2470
2300
1890
2180
2340
2490
2300
1900
2130
2370
2440
2430
2050
2220
2400
2550
2060
1960
1890
2240
2490
2070
1920
1870
2330
2490
2170
1840
1970
2240
2570
2140
1810
1930
2270
2530
2080
1720
1970
2340
2510
2070
1680
1990
2310
2410
1990
1710
1970
2260
2470
2010
1620
1910
2270
2430
1840
1720
1960
2090
2240
1820
1680
2030
2070
2190
1820
1710
1970
2010
2160
1770
1670
1980
2050
2080
1620
1440
1710
1870
2120
1610
1470
1720
1820
2070
1690
1340
1770
1920
2080
1610
1540
1740
1960
2140
1730
1620
1710
1910
2230
1690
1580
1770
1870
2170
1740
1690
1730
1910
2210
1750
1590
1760
1930
2170
1840
1880
2030
2110
2240
1940
1740
2030
2090
2390
1910
1840
2190
2120
2270
1940
1840
2090
2160
2370
1930
1720
1870
1980
2210
1990
1670
1830
1920
2110
1910
1740
1890
1920
2170
1840
1760
1820
1990
2190
2080
1990
2230
2340
2470
2080
1910
2150
2310
2460
2120
1950
2200
2280
2520
2140
1970
2220
2320
2550
2610
2240
2387
2520
2560
2470
2210
2490
2450
2630
2510
2170
2420
2440
2580
2490
2270
2380
2520
2620
2610
2460
2520
2540
2760
2690
2530
2590
2630
2750
2680
2480
2630
2690
2770
2630
2420
2570
2580
2740
2170
2420
2440
2580
2490
2270
2380
2520
2620
2580

Comment: Maybe try fitting an AR process?

Comment: How did you find the parameters for the first series? From a rough visual look at the series, it seems like it has some persistence that your second simulated series does not have (plus some short-term ciclicality that is close to seasonality because it seems fairly regular, but this is not the main point here and should be confirmed by something else than visual inspection). What seems clear is that is either a very persistent stationary process that keeps coming back to 2000 or even a I(1). In any case it is far more persistent than yours, that seems a stationary process with not much memory

Comment: So I suspect that the problem may be that you have not estimated the parameters very well. Was the first series a simulated series as well? or was it a real-world example with real data? consider that you are focusing on the shape of the pdf in your question, but here the estimated parameters are very important. Once you get an accurate estimate of the parameters, then, you can use them with a random innovation (possibly from the same marginal pdf as the original series 1) to simulate.

Comment: At that point, depending on the properties of the series (firstly depending on stationarity and secondly depending on the presence of trends etc.) you may or may not have a similar graph. Consider the case of a random walk without drift, which is by definition fully dependent on innovations. In that case, since the the future level of the process is just a function of current level and innovations, you may have a completely different graph in the simulation as the simulated innovations change compared to the historical innovations of series 1. If a trend exist, it may reduce the discrepancy.

Comment: This is a question where I gotta ask: why? What is the goal that you are trying to achieve? There is a lot of different ways to interpret the stated goal to "generate a similar time series". The most "similar" time series is the original series itself. If you want a similar time series, what should be different? I would also echo the sentiment of @Fr1 which is that your data is clearly not a stationary random process, so modelling it as a stationary lognormal process will clearly not capture the high- and low-frequency trends that are obvious in your oringinal data.

Comment: @Fr1: I did a distribution fitting procedure; histogram and selecting another distribution based on KS and Chi-Squared tests. Lognormal scored better on KS D critical value basis. But I have not incorporated any trend proprties

Comment: @timchap: the data is collected from experts. the required was to plug the 250 days data into an optimization model. that is a decision has been made. my role is to simulate 20 scenarios that are equivalent to the data in order to plug them into the optimization model, not a future forecast

Comment: So I suppose that you are using real data, my suggestion is to forget about the shape of the pdf for a while and focus on the parameter estimation for at least your conditional mean.. the idea is that it is likely that there will exists a better specification of the model compared to yours.. but this is not about the pdf, this is about the structure of your conditional mean.. are you using an Arma/Ma/Ar/Arima? Etc. I suppose you are in a univariate setting here.. Since the QMLE is still consistent if you mispecify the pdf function, then the pdf FOR THE MOMENT is not the most relevant thing.

Comment: *"the required was to plug the 250 days data into an optimization model. that is a decision has been made."* could you explain more about this optimization model and the 'decision' that has to be made. It seems to me like you sort of want to generate ['made up data'](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/420525/best-term-for-made-up-data) in order to test those optimization models. This seems like a valid approach. But details are lacking. In addition it is complex as this question mixes two concepts: 1 how to correctly fit the data 2 how to simulate 'made up data' for a specific purpose.

Comment: Well have you done your research ?. You probably are concerned with how do you accomplish this with the tools you have on hand.  I  have laid out a working approach here in great detail. I was able to simulate a number of look-alikes ...personally reinforcing my suggested approach .  which has never been published (that I am aware of !)  but is dead-on in terms of fulfilling your reasonable expectations. @Martin is dead on suggesting the need to "make-up data"

Comment: In order to proceed .. please restate your question ...e.g. How do I simulate a new series  with the same characteristics (equation) as the series that I have observed ?

Answer (score 1):

"I was interested to know its probability distribution and see if it fits other distributions"  ... there is no reason to model the observed series which can be reduced to simpler structure.  Failing modelling attempts one simple uses monte-carlo procedures using the cdf of the observed series to generate values for the composite BUT not time series traces.

There is no need to transform your data see the following for clues on power transforms [When (and why) should you take the log of a distribution (of numbers)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/when-and-why-should-you-take-the-log-of-a-distribution-of-numbers)

What I propose here is a 2 step procedure 1) characterize the series ..separating observed to signal and noise AND then 2) simulating white noise and using it to render a data realization of the model .

It is important to characterize the series i.e identify the nature of the "curves" . In this way you can separate the data into signal and noise and focus on simulating trial/candidate noise processes leading to "similar time series" i.e. time series with nearly identical acf.

In this way after a useful model has been identified one can then use simulated error processes and then "reverse" the model by injecting/inputting the simulated error processes to generate a trial realization of the data. This is essentially how one generates a forecast and the probability distribution to assess prediction limits for a given interval of time BUT we will not be forecasting here.

Please post your actual 250 data points and I and others might be able to help you further.

EDITED AFTER RECEIPT OF YOUR 250 OBSERVATIONS :

One of the reasons I asked you to post your data is that I have long been a fan of simulation (dating back to the mid-sixties) as an objective  way of evaluating strategies and suggested procedures. As I developed and improved model identification strategies , I conducted simulation of data in order to evaluate signal detection. I always have maintained a currency in simulation as a possible lithmus test.

I  took your 250 values and used AUTOBOX , a piece of software that not only has model identification BUT data simulation capabilities. I used it to take your data and identify the following model in order to separate signal and noise and then to use the model as the basis for simulations.

Here is the ACF of the orig[image]inal series . AUTOBOX rendered a model here [image] with residuals here [image] and acf here [image]

The Actual & Fitted values are plotted here[image]

Now the Histogram of the original 250 values is here and is shown for completeness sake [image] while the histogram of the error series from our model is here [image] and much more important in our exercise.

We now proceed to use the simulation option in AUTOBOX which requires a model , presented here in a structured manner [image]

We ask the software to generate 0,1 random numbers and use them as the basis (input) into the model form to create a 250 period realization . This can then be repeated for as many replications of the 250 simulated values.

I show here the acf of the original 250 values [image] and the acf of the first replication of the 250 simulated values [image] . The simulated series "resembles" the original series which is what I think you want to do.

Your question could have/should have been worded more correctly. I guess you now how to modify your question given my answer. I suggest you do so.

I suggest that you get hold of a good simulation piece of software ( and there are a few !) to allow you to specify the required equation for the generated simulation OR write your own code to do this .

[image] presents the relationship between an error process (perhaps the result of simulation) and the realization in terms of Y

Comment: I posted the data, can you guide me?

Comment: Wow! Now this will need some serious understanding from my side as this is my first time to do time series. But at least, where in this is the method to simulate different scenarios of the same time series without forecasting

Comment: if you can characterize thus separating signal & noise via  a FILTER AND then vary the noise BUT not it's nature & then use it you can get a "new series" .Simulation is the CONVERSE  of modelling . With modelling you convert or filter the original series to render a "simpler series" . With simulation you do tjhe converse you take a set of a set of values and inject it via the INVERSE FILTER read model in order to generate a new series with similar characteristics as the original series.  I have often characterized myself as a wannabe "noise maker"  via efficient characterizarion/modelling.

Comment: there was no forecasting done at all .. The underlying model was detected and then useful in separating signal to fit and a white noise set of errors. time series modelling is a bi-directional approach i.e.  y via a filter leads to a stochastic process white noise ... white noise (possibly simulated !)  via an inverse filter leads to y.